# IE10: iframe.contentWindow.name returns iframe.name

Tags: jquery, json, api, iframe, internet-explorer-10

```
function addIframe(name, src) {
    var iframe_html = "" + "<iframe" + ' name="' + name + '"' + ' src="' + src + '"' + ' style="display: none;"' + "></iframe>";
    var $iframe = $(iframe_html).appendTo(container);
    return $iframe
}


var $iframe = addIframe(iname, isrc);
    $iframe.data("back", false).bind("load", function() {
        var response = $iframe[0].contentWindow.name;
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

This is a part from the jQuery WNT plugin v1.0 from http://noteslog.com/wnt.
Chrome / FF log the API answer in an JSON formatted array in the console, which was requested in the iframe, that's correct. But only IE10 doesn't return the JSON array, but the name of the iframe! IE8-IE9 work as expected, like Chrome / FF.

The iframe:

```
<iframe name="iframe1373559930801" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Only IE10 prints "iframe1373559930801" instead of the JSON array from within the iframe.